# AHK - Tool not clicking Chrome button in Multiloginapp

Tags: autohotkey

I have a GUI that contains a 'Start app' button which leads to a launch of http://multitaskapp.com, waiting 30 seconds, and clicking on the Chrome app in the Browser profiles. I thought the `sleep` function would allow the app to wait for the multiloginapp to complete loading and then click inside the app.

```
;; GUI input
: -------------------------------
: ---------------------------------------
Gui, Show, w300 h300, Steam Tool

Gui, Add, Button, x10 y20 gStart, Start the tool
return

; Labels
; -----------------------
; --------------------------------

Start:
    Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Multiloginapp\multiloginapp.exe
    WinActivate, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
    WinWaitActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
    Sleep, 30
    Click 817, 240
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinActivate only makes sense if the window exists.
Try WinWait before it:

```
Start:
    Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Multiloginapp\multiloginapp.exe
    WinWait, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
    IfWinNotActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15, ,WinActivate, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
    WinWaitActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
    Sleep, 500  ; 0,5 seconds.  For waiting 30 seconds use "Sleep, 30000"
    Click 817, 240
    ; ---
return
```

**EDIT**

If you have to wait for 30 seconds, try this:

```
Start:
    Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Multiloginapp\multiloginapp.exe
    WinWait, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
    Sleep, 30000
    IfWinNotActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15, ,WinActivate, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
    WinWaitActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
    Sleep, 200
    Click 817, 240
    ; ---
return
```

Comment: Thanks, but after changing the delay to 30 seconds, the click command is still not opening the browser.

Comment: If you have to wait for so long a time (30 seconds), you should (re)activate the program-window after that period. See my edited answer.